# How can I execute an android emulator within an app for Desktop

Tags: android, android-emulator, virtual-machine, windows

I am developing an android app, but I am searching for a desktop app that can execute a Virtual Machine running Android OS. This desktop app should also be able to install an `apk` file to the VM by the press of a button. I have searched many pages and sites but haven't found one that runs on windows desktop or one that can be executed via the command line.

Is it possible to embed a virtual machine in a windows desktop app? If it is  possible how do I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for, as I am unfamiliar with some of the terms you used, but [BlueStacks](http://www.bluestacks.com/?bst_cmp=rptmgmt_us&gclid=CMHYk8_3jsQCFU8vgQodcLEApg) might be worth a shot.

Comment: my idea is something like this simulator but to make one like that

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you question then, nor this response. Are you making a simulator? Making an app and wanting to test it on your simulator?

Comment: my idea is  basically is embed an emulator in window for app desktop is possible

Comment: A form? What do you mean by a form?

Comment: Oh, okay. I don't know. Sorry.

Comment: BlueStacks not  is  open source, I need  embed a android   emulator  in my  project.

Answer (score 0):

Check WindowsAndroid i think is what you need.

[HERE](http://windowsandroid.uptodown.com/)

Comment: not, basically  is  embed an emulator  in window for  app  desktop